# Network communication across two private network

Tags: networking, communication, p2p, xen

I am trying to implement a peer to peer communication ..

I use sockets for communication between them. I want to know if there are any ways i can use the same sort of communication when the two peers are behind two private Networks (They dont know each others public ip address.) I can think of a shared buffer in a well known location as a means of communication. But is there some other way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You may also have to consider the case where two peers don't even have public IP addresses, in which case you could use [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT) techniques to avoid the need for a central server. STUN has been used effectively in products such as Skype (I think), but it remains quite a black art at this stage.

For a central approach, consider [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), of which [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) is a very popular implementation. Various other messaging protocols exist as well, such as the emerging AMPQ standard.

These technologies are likely to be more robust and scalable than a home-grown socket-based protocol.

Answer (score 0):

STUN and TURN are the common ways to achieve this as already posted and are standards based approaches. However, I have seen a really interesting approach to doing this using icmp messages recently. [It's called pwnat, and available here](http://samy.pl/pwnat/)

Answer (score 0):

Since both are in different private networks, both peers cannot communicate with each other.
You need to have a public server in place, so that you can establish connection via that server. 
Refer resiprocate , [Resiprocate](http://www.resiprocate.org) for details